# Arithmetic overflow in C++ adding 2 DWORDs

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error:

> Warning   C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2).

In the following code:

```
stream_name_offset + wsi->dwStreamNameSize <= wsi_buffer_size;
```

The first 2 are `DWORD`s and 3rd one is a `size_t`.

How do I avoid this warning? I tried casing the 2 fields to `size_t` but it still produces the warning.

Comment: Try `(0LLU + stream_name_offset + wsi->dwStreamNameSize) <= wsi_buffer_size`. This forces the participants of plus to be a longer type and should get the promotion stuff right.  DWORD are 32-bit unsigned, and 0LLU forces promotion to 64-bit math during addition.

Comment: Hmm, I can't repro this. Are you sure of the given types? You're building for x64, right? Which edition of Visual Studio?

Comment: @SteveFriedl The latest 2019, for some reason when I restarted Visual Studio it disappeared when I tried compiling again, just strange.

Comment: A compiler went away just from restarting? I thought that kind of thing only happened with operating system. Huh.

Comment: What context was this in?  An `if` test?

Comment: It's inside an `assert`. Before I restarted it I was debugging some run-time error, maybe that's related, no idea. It's more a warning than an error but still strange.

Comment: There was another warning and both went away.

Comment: Yeah, casting one of the operands should already be sufficient, let alone both, to get it right. Of course the warning is correct and the code as presented is wrong for sufficiently large stream size and offset. Whether the rest of the program would work if the stream arguments are only 32 bit wide but the contents may be larger is hard to tell, of course ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered what I did wrong. Thanks to Steve Friedl and everyone who looked at it.

It turns out the error was caused by me using "Run Code Analysis on Solution" instead of "build", while the compiled binary was running.

When this happens, Visual Studio has a strange quirk where it keeps on saying you have the same errors, even if you do modify the file.

When the binary stopped running, casing the first parameter to `size_t` alone indeed fixes things. For safety I cast both to `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to explicitly promote type before the sum with a c-like cast. You can do this in this way: `(unsigned long)stream_name_offset + (unsigned long)wsi->dwStreamNameSize <= wsi_buffer_size;`

In other case, when there are more than one data types in the expression, C++ language adopts the "Implicit Type Coversion"(type promotion) so all the data types of the variables are upgraded to the data type of the variable with largest data type. This is the hierarchy:

> bool -> char -> short int -> int ->  unsigned int -> long -> unsigned
>   ->  long long -> float -> double -> long double

With implicit conversion you have to pay attention on signed variable when converted to unsigned one, the sign will be lost.